# HTML form is not encoding the URL of the search in Velocity

Tags: html, forms, urlencode, velocity

I'm having an issue with the URL encoding of a search query, I have this in a [Velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Velocity) template.

```
<form method="GET" action="$req.contextPath/plugins/peopledirectory/search.action">
    <div class="greyboxfill" style="width: 420px">
        <input type="hidden" name="pageId" value="$pageId"/>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" size="30" value="$search"/>
        <input type="submit" name="searchbtn" value="Pesquisar">
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that when I click the submit button, the search string is not URL encoded and if I search for something like ME&A, it only searches for ME. Is there any definition needed in Velocity to make that work?

I seen around the web that the form HTML tag has a inner URL encoding, why is it not working in this case?

Comment: This doesn't look like has something to do with Velocity. Do you see encoded data in browser's url field? I see that your form is not in English, maybe you type `&` character in a different encoding so it can't recognize it?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is explicitly escape the string using [EscapeTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html#url%28%29) from [VelocityTools](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/). This is an additional library that you'll need to download and then include in your velocity context.

URL encoding is then as easy as:

```
$escape.url($search)
```